# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef') in Next.js / framer-motion blog project

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')` upon usage of `useMotionValue`, or any other function from 'framer-motion'.

Here is my React component

```
'use client'

import { motion, useMotionTemplate, useMotionValue } from 'framer-motion'
import Link from 'next/link'

// import LikeCounter from './like-counter'
import Image from '~/components/mdx/image'
// import ViewCounter from './view-counter'

import type { MdxFrontMatter } from '~/types'
import { useFormattedDate } from '~/hooks/use-formatted-date'

type PostCardProps = MdxFrontMatter

const PostCard = (props: PostCardProps) => {
  const { _id, slug, coverImage, title, summary, date } = props
  const formattedDate = useFormattedDate(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')

  const mouseX = useMotionValue(0)
  const mouseY = useMotionValue(0)

  return (
    <Link
      key={_id}
      href={`/blog/${slug}`}
      className="border-accent-2 group relative flex flex-col space-y-3 rounded-2xl border p-6"
      onMouseMove={(e) => {
        const { left, top } = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect()

        mouseX.set(e.clientX - left)
        mouseY.set(e.clientY - top)
      }}
    >
      <motion.div
        className="pointer-events-none absolute -inset-px rounded-xl opacity-0 transition duration-300 [--spotlight:rgba(0,0,0,0.05)] group-hover:opacity-100 dark:[--spotlight:rgba(255,255,255,0.15)]"
        style={{
          background: useMotionTemplate`
            radial-gradient(
              650px circle at ${mouseX}px ${mouseY}px,
              var(--spotlight),
              transparent 80%
            )
          `,
        }}
      />
      <Image
        src={`/static/images/blog-covers/${coverImage}`}
        width={1280}
        height={720}
        alt={title}
        rounded="rounded-lg"
      />
      <div className="flex-grow space-y-4">
        <h2 className="text-xl font-bold">{title}</h2>
        <div className="text-accent-5">{summary}</div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex items-center text-sm">{formattedDate ? formattedDate : '...'}</div>
    </Link>
  )
}

export default PostCard
```

And my package.json is the following:

```
  {
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=3434 next-remote-watch ./data",
    "dev": "PORT=3434 next dev",
    "postinstall": "prisma generate",
    "build": "next build && tsx ./scripts/generate-sitemap",
    "serve": "PORT=3435 next start",
    "analyze": "cross-env ANALYZE=true next build",
    "lint": "next lint --fix --dir pages --dir components --dir lib --dir layouts --dir scripts --dir pages",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "typecheck": "npx tsc -b",
    "upgrade": "rimraf package-lock.json && npx taze major -w && ni"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@next/font": "^13.4.4",
    "@octokit/graphql": "^5.0.5",
    "@prisma/client": "^4.14.0",
    "@tabler/icons-react": "^2.22.0",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.9",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "clsx": "^1.2.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.8",
    "esbuild": "^0.17.19",
    "framer-motion": "^10.12.12",
    "github-slugger": "^2.0.0",
    "gray-matter": "^4.0.3",
    "image-size": "^1.0.2",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^4.0.2",
    "mdx-bundler": "^9.2.1",
    "next": "^13.4.2",
    "next-themes": "^0.2.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.23",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.3.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.44.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.12.1",
    "react-share": "^4.4.1",
    "reading-time": "^1.5.0",
    "rehype-autolink-headings": "^6.1.1",
    "rehype-preset-minify": "^6.0.0",
    "rehype-prism-plus": "^1.5.1",
    "rehype-slug": "^5.1.0",
    "remark-gfm": "^3.0.1",
    "sharp": "^0.32.1",
    "smoothscroll-polyfill": "^0.4.4",
    "swr": "^2.1.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "typed.js": "^2.0.132"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^17.6.3",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^17.6.3",
    "@next/bundle-analyzer": "^13.4.2",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^8.0.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "dedent": "^0.7.0",
    "eslint": "^8.40.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.4.2",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "globby": "^13.1.4",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "inquirer": "^9.2.3",
    "lint-staged": "^13.2.2",
    "next-remote-watch": "^2.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.2.8",
    "prisma": "^4.14.0",
    "rehype": "^12.0.1",
    "remark-frontmatter": "^4.0.1",
    "remark-parse": "^10.0.1",
    "remark-stringify": "^10.0.2",
    "tsx": "^3.12.7",
    "typescript": "5.0.4",
    "unified": "^10.1.2",
    "unist-util-visit": "^4.1.2"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.+(js|jsx|ts|tsx)": [
      "eslint --fix"
    ],
    "*.+(js|jsx|ts|tsx|json|css)": [
      "prettier --write"
    ]
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "esbuild-linux-64": "^0.15.18"
  }
}
```

I digged various forums and iterated on different versions of React, reinstalled packages, checked things and libraries are the right places, I cannot make sense of this.